# Adding shopify collection time frame condition

Tags: collections, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need someone to help me with a code that I can use to make a time frame for my bestseller collection on Shopify. Normally, the bestseller automated collection covers all time, but I need it to just cover the best selling products in 30days.

Answer (score 0):

In your Liquid, whenever you render that collection, you have access to all the products currently in the collection. Examine each product. Assuming you somehow have access to a date assigned to the product resource that helps you, you could hide products in the Best Seller list that do not qualify to be shown. That is probably the easiest route you have. Just like hiding search results you don't like, or hiding products that are out of stock, you use Liquid in decide if a product in the Best Seller listing is shown or not.

Comment: do you have a code that can be used to work on this from the theme end, that will make the whole process automated?

Comment: That approach is automated. That being said, the exercise in playing with the small amount of Liquid needed is up to you. Have fun!